# ionic3 - the view did not update after the value change

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

the display about the value of the slider does not update after i change the value of the slider
Here is my code:
html:

```
  <ion-range min="1" max="24" pin= "true" [(ngModel)]="time">
    <p range-left>1</p>
    <p range-right>24</p>
  </ion-range>
  <p>{{purchasePrice}}</p>
```

ts:

```
 time : number 
 purchasePrice = 10 * this.time
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to use (ionChange) and update values in that function

```
<ion-range min="1" max="24" pin= "true" (ionChange)="updateTime()" [(ngModel)]="time">
        <p range-left>1</p>
        <p range-right>24</p>
      </ion-range>
      <p>{{purchasePrice}}</p>
```

Controller Code:

```
export class HomePage {
time : number ;
 purchasePrice = 0;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  updateTime(){
    this.purchasePrice =  10 * this.time;
  }

}
```

for live check [demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-x7boir)

Comment: i tried your code but it still now work in my project.i find that the display of the {{purchasePrice}} only update when i press the back button.I have print the purchasePrice in the console.The value of purchasePrice is changed real-time

Comment: Can u elaborate your problem ?

Comment: The display still not change in the view but value change in the console

Comment: your code is work in a blank project.so i think this is the problem of my project.

Comment: I tried to rebuild a project.I find that the value can display in the HomePage Correctly but i put the code in the childPage.The value cant display correctly.